# Can't send entire user to API json response, only send id and email

Tags: json, api, symfony

I'm tring to send back to front end my user entity, but only id and email are sent, not others proprities.
The other proprities are using @Groups like id and email. Like you will see, I can't send in response id and email. So I don't understand where is the problem.
I have the `use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;`

My Entity User:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups("apiv0")
     */
    private $id;

    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     * @Groups("apiv0")
     */
    private $roles = [];
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @Groups("apiv0")
     */
    private $email;
    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Groups("apiv0")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Bloodsugar::class, mappedBy="user")
     * @Groups("apiv0")
     */
    private $bloodsugars;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Groups("apiv0")
     */
    private $lastname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Groups("apiv0")
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     * @Groups("apiv0")
     */
    private $target_min;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     * @Groups("apiv0")
     */
    private $target_max;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @Groups("apiv0")
     */
    private $doctor_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     * @Groups("apiv0")
     */
    private $diabetes_type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @Groups("apiv0")
     */
    private $doctor_email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Groups("apiv0")
     */
    private $created_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups("apiv0")
     */
    private $username;
```

My Controller:

```php
$userCreated =  $repository->find($user->getId());
                    
                    dump($user);
                    dump($userCreated);
                
                    $response = $this->json($userCreated, 200, [], ['groups' => 'apiv0']);

                    dd($response);

                    return $response
```

My dumps:

[image]

Comment: ....is there any good reason to put the password to an API response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use graph bracket in the groups definition, so do like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
 * @Groups({"apiv0"})
 */
private $email;
```

instead of this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
 * @Groups("apiv0")
 */
private $email;
```

Comment: Fantastic, that works so good, thank you very much. I used without {} in my precedent project and it worked. Can you tell me why not in this one ?